# Elasticsearch data issue

Tags: elasticsearch

Today I faced a weird problem with elasticsearch and I don't know how to fix the issue. The scenrario is somewhat like this

- Elasticsearch cluster with 2 nodes :
  Total docs 1000
- Now one of my server goes down and all write and reads are handled by second server. Now say there are 10000 docs in the ES2.
- Due to system problem now whole elasticsearch network is down and both ES1 and ES2 are down. Now somehow I manually go and make ES1 up and now its taking all the write requests.
- ES2 comes up and now discovers ES1 as its master.
- ES2 syncs up with master and all the data written to ES2 node is lost.

Is there any way to recover the lost data. Is this an expected behaviour in distributed system?

Please let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: And what did you expect? How should have ES merged the data from the two "independent" nodes of the same cluster?

Comment: This is the reason why `minimum_master_nodes` setting exist: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-zen.html#master-election. To prevent split-brains. You didn't have, technically, a split-brain, but because you allowed different writes to both nodes, separately, your cluster behaved like it was in a split-brain situation. In a two node cluster `minimum_master_nodes` should be 2. Not ideal, but that's why the recommendation is to have a odd number of nodes in a cluster.

Comment: @AndreiStefan: wouldn't it be good if elasticsearch merged the docs with different ids and on conflict gave preference to master?

Comment: Maybe, but this is not how Elasticsearch is working. `minimum_master_nodes` is a must! And no, you can't recover that data.

Comment: fyi: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8345#issuecomment-61794655